# Is there a Cayley resolvent for sextic polynomials?

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory

I have no Galois Theory knowledge and a specific sextic polynomial that I'd like to prove has roots that are inexpressible with radicals. Putting it into Wolfram Alpha yields only approximations, but I'm looking for a more rigorous argument than this.

Searching on Wikipedia, I found out about [Cayley's Resolvent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Cayley%27s_resolvent), which provides a nice deterministic test for when the roots of a quintic are expresssible with radicals. Is there an analogue for sextics (or even higher dimensions)? If so, could someone point me towards a paper or book where this test is proven (or even just reputably claimed) to work, for the purpose of citation?

Comment: Yes, what is that sextic polynomial?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I worked it out a while ago, and have lost my notes where I worked it out. It is specific, but as of this moment, unknown. I should point out too: it has integer coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thomas Hagedorn's 1999 paper [General Formulas for Solvable Sextic Equations](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82641766.pdf) uses two resolvents of degrees $10$ and $15$, denoted $f_{10}$ and $f_{15}$ respectively – necessary because two groups of orders $48$ and $72$ are needed to exactly cover all transitive solvable groups on $6$ elements as subgroups – to determine solvability of a sextic. At least one of the following has to hold:

- $f_{10}$ has a rational root
- $f_{15}$ has a rational root of multiplicity not $5$
- $f_{15}$ has a rational root of multiplicity $5$ and $f_{10}$'s $\mathbb Q$-irreducible factorisation has degrees $4,6$

---

If the Galois group is contained in the order-$72$ group there is a quadratic extension over which the sextic splits into two cubics. If contained in the order-$48$ group there is a cubic extension over which the sextic splits into a quadratic and quartic.

Comment: That's exactly what I want... aside from the enormous complexity of the resolvents. Thank you!

Comment: This is good! You wouldn't happen to remember those two groups? My guess is that they are the group of 48 symmetries of a cube acting on the six faces and the wreath product $S_3\wr C_2$ with the two copies of $S_3$ acting on their respective triples and $C_2$ then interchanging the two triples. Is it difficult to see that all the solvable subgroups of $S_6$ are contained in one or the other?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen 6T11 and 6T13 for the order-$48/72$ groups respectively in LMFDB: $S_4×C_2$ and $C_2^3:D_4$.