# What is the algebraic solution (not graphical) of $2x^6+4x^5+x^4+4x^3+2x^2+1=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am looking for the algebraic solution (not graphical) of the following equation.

$$2x^6+4x^5+x^4+4x^3+2x^2+1=0$$

According to the definition given in Wikipedia, this polynomial is not a palindromic polynomial, unfortunately.

But, a math student claims that the above polynomial has an algebraic solution. Our highschool teachers couldn't solve this.

Dividing each side by $x^4$, I get

$$2x^2+4x+1+\frac{4}{x}+\frac {2}{x^2}+\frac {1}{x^4}=0$$

So

$$2\bigg(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)+4\bigg(x+\frac {1}{x}\bigg)+\bigg(1+\frac{1}{x^4}\bigg)=0$$

I know that the property $$x^2+\frac {1}{x^2}=\bigg(x+\frac {1}{x}\bigg)^2-2$$

But the term $1+\frac {1}{x^4}$ violates the symmetry.  What can I do from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of Sagemath (another Computer Algebra System), I have found that the given polynomial $p$ factors over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as:
$$p(x) = 2 \left(x^3 + \left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + 1\right) x^2 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + 1 \right) \left( x^3 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + 1\right) x^2 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + 1\right).$$
Now the roots of both of the cubic factors can be solved using the Cardano equation.

In retrospect, given the form of the factorization of $p$, you could put together a reverse-engineered type of solution for how somebody lucky might have come up with it: note that
$$2 (x^3+x^2+1)^2 = 2x^6 + 4x^5 + 2x^4 + 4x^3 + 4x^2 + 2.$$
Therefore,
$$p(x) = 2(x^3+x^2+1)^2 - (x^4 + 2x^2 + 1) = 2(x^3+x^2+1)^2 - (x^2+1)^2.$$

Comment: Nicely done (+1). For the reverse-engineering part, with a lot of imagination the $x^4+2x^2+1$ terms *could* suggest grouping in $\,(x^2+1)\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
2x^6+4x^5+x^4+4x^3+2x^2+1 &= 2x^6 + 4 x^3(x^2+1) + (x^2+1)^2 \color{red}{ + (x^2+1)^2 -  (x^2+1)^2}
\\ &= 2(x^3 + x^2 + 1)^2 - (x^2+1)^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $2 x^6 + 4 x^5 + x^4 + 4 x^3 + 2 x^2 + 1$ is an irreducible sextic, but according to Maple it has a solvable Galois group "6T13" of size $72$, which makes the equation solvable by radicals.
Unfortunately Maple doesn't tell what the solution by radicals is.  I suspect it's rather complicated.  In principle a recipe for it is given in Hagedorn, [General Formulas for Solving Solvable Sextic Equations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186930098428X)

Comment: Hello . Who is Maple ?

Comment: @mathtime You mean what is?

Comment: Maple is a [Computer Algebra System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system).

Answer (score 1):

The following picks up where @[RobertIsrael](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4715129/291201) left off:

> according to Maple it has a solvable Galois group "6T13" of size $72$, which makes the equation solvable by radicals

Quoting from @[ParclyTaxel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/357390/parcly-taxel)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4331523/291201) to another question about solvable sextics:

> If the Galois group is contained in the order-$72$ group there is a quadratic extension over which the sextic splits into two cubics.

In OP's case the reciprocal of the polynomial is a depressed sextic, so the reciprocals of the factors must be depressed cubics, in other words the factorization would look like the following, where $a,b$ are roots of some rational quadratics, and $\bar a, \bar b$ are their rational conjugates.

$$
\begin{align}
p(x) &= 2(x^3 + ax^2+b)(x^3+\bar a x^2+\bar b) \tag{1}
\\ &= 2\big(x^6 + (a+\bar a)x^5 + a \bar a x^4 + (b+\bar b) x^3 + (a \bar b + \bar a b) x^2 + b \bar b\big)
\end{align}
$$

Identifying coefficients gives:

$$
\begin{align}
2(a + \bar a) = 4 \tag{2}
\\ 2a\bar a = 1 \tag{3}
\\ 2(b+\bar b) = 4 \tag{4}
\\ 2(a\bar b + b\bar a) = 2 \tag{5}
\\ 2 b \bar b = 1 \tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

Equations $(2),(3)$ and respectively $(4),(6)$ imply that $a,b$ are the roots of the same quadratic $\,t^2 - 2 t + \frac{1}{2}\,$, so $a,b = 1 \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,  and the combination which also satisfies $(5)$ is $a = b$.

Substituting $\,a = b = 1 - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\,$, $\,\bar a = \bar b = 1 + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\,$ in $(1)$ gives the same factorization as derived in @[DanielSchepler](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/337888/daniel-schepler)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4715227/291201):

$$p(x) = 2 \left(x^3 + \left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) x^2 + 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) \left( x^3 + \left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) x^2 + 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

*Just for the fun of **not** using Cardano's method*

As given by answers
$$P= 2 \left(x^3 + \left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) x^2 + 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) \left( x^3 + \left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) x^2 + 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$

The real solution of the first cubic is just
$$x=-\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{6}  \left(1+2 \cosh
   \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(82+54
   \sqrt{2}\right)\right)\right)$$ and for the second cubic
$$x=-\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{6}  \left(1+2 \cosh
   \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(82-54
   \sqrt{2}\right)\right)\right)$$

This is done by hand following the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions).